# OIDC Client encoding URL during SigninRedirectCallback

Tags: angular, oidc-client-js, oidc-client

I'm building an app with an external Identity Server. Login works fine, only when being sent back to the signin-oidc page something weird happens.

I'm using the HashLocationStrategy so the URL looks like this.

```
http://localhost:4200/#/signin-oidc#id_token=....
```

But after some seconds loading this page it seems like the URL is being encoded after the first # which makes it looks like this:

```
http://localhost:4200/#%2Fsignin-oidc%23id_token=....
```

This causes my app to redirect to the 404 page.

The login redirect callback function looks like this:

```
this.manager.signinRedirectCallback().then((user: User) => {
    if (user) {
        this.user = user;
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
    }
});
```

It doesn't reach the router navigate function, so that's not the issue. Could anybody maybe help me with this issue?

Comment: can you show your redirectUrl inside the config

Comment: It's http://localhost:4200/#/signin-oidc#

Answer (score 0):

oidc-client try to find always  the last hash delimiter in the redirect url, change your **redirect_uri** to:

```
redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:4200/#/auth-callback#',
```

i suggest that you add a handler component for that

```
{ path: 'auth-callback', component: HandlerComponent },
```

with content

```
export class HandlerComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(private authService: AuthService, private route: Router) {}
ngOnInit() {
  this.authService.completeAuthentication().then((args) => {
    this.route.navigate(['/home']);
  });
 }
}
```

and service

```
completeAuthentication(): Promise<void> {
 return this._userManager.signinRedirectCallback().then((user) => {
    this._user = user; // get the new user
 });
}
```

Comment: This is exactly how i implemented my code, so that's why I think what it does is quite weird. There is no hard redirect happening and no Router function is happening, so somewhere the location hash is being changed.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to de-serialize the URL params OnInit

so for instance:

```
decodeURIComponent(string)
```

after retrieving the the decoded URL call your signinRedirectCallback()

Comment: I put an event handler on hashchange, but before thee handler functions finishes the application redirects to the 404 page already